# Int from public to static

Tags: java, static, public

**Before you read my question, know that I am bad in English**

```
public Name()
{
   ID = 1;
   loadOptions();
}

private void loadOptions
{
   // code
   if (as[0].equals("ID"))
   {
      ID = Integer.parseInt(as[1]);
   }
   // more code
}

static
{
   ID1 = ID;
}
```

ID1 is 0, but i want that it is `Integer.parseInt(as[1]);`... Please help me!

Comment: Help us by rewriting your question.

Comment: Help us by adding the relevant language tag to your question.

Comment: Can you share some more code ? Are you saying that you want to have ID1 = value from as[1] in the static block ?

Comment: i assume this is a java question.  But i still don't fully understand it - what are loadoptions parameters?

Comment: So why can't you say `ID1 = Integer.parseInt(as[1]);`?  The static block runs first so you have to change the value at runtime when you get the value.

Comment: No it is an example... But i want the id in the static...

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve this:

1. Once you parse as[1], assign the result also to ID1
2. Make the as array static, and load it before initializing ID1

Comment: "Make the as array static, and load it before initializing ID1" Can you please make an example?

Comment: static String as[] = new String[] { "ID", "42" };

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be lacking some fundamentals of the language.

The static initialisation block only runs the first time the class is referenced.

A constructor runs every time you instantiate an instance of a class.

I assume ID1 is a static variable, and you are trying to initialise it in the static area which runs before the constructors have a chance to execute.

Just because the code is written in a certain order does not mean it runs on that order.

assuming you really want to set ID1 to whatever ID is, you have to do this

```
public Name()
{
   ID = 1;
   loadOptions();
   ID1 = ID;
}
```

of course, it you do not construct an instance of Name, ID1 will remain 0 until an instance is created